# Clearing IDLE's shell for Python

Tags: python

So I'm doing an MIT OCW assignment where I am creating a functional game of hangman. I got everything working. In IDLE, I have to hit F5 to run the code in the shell. I don't know any other way to run it, but that's not the big deal to me.

The main problem: the shell gets absolutely full of responses. It just keeps stacking up with more and more output. So, my question. Is it possible to put in a piece of code to clear the shell? Or do I just have to deal with it for now?

EDIT: To clarify:
I need the prints for each cycle. Every time the user guesses a letter, it prints something like this:

2 guesses remaining

Possible answers: abdfghijkpquvwxyz

Guess a letter:g

That letter is not in the word!

_ o_ _ _ tr_

I just want to know if there is a way I can clear what is in the shell before the next 'cycle' is printed.

Comment: Can you remove the code that creates the responses? To me it sounds like you wrote a lot of print statments and now you want to add more code to prevent them from printing. Maybe you can remove my confusion about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close it and just open a new one when you want to run the program or run it from the terminal and use use `clear` after you exit the shell

Comment: I have been just closing the shell and running it again. You can see my edit for more details on what I'm looking for.

Comment: You might be able to accomplish that by turning your script into an executable with `chmod` and using `os` to send a `clear` command to the terminal.

Comment: I was thinking hat I might need to just do that. I'm pretty new to all of this, but I might start looking into how to do that. I completed all I have to do for the assignment, I'm just looking at little extra things I can do to it. Thanks!